# Working with VBA formulas

Tags: excel, vba

I'm iterating over all the rows in my worksheet. Traversing from the bottom to the top.  I want to SUM the previous 12 values in the row and I am trying to use the offset R[]C[] notation for a relative position, but this case crashes VBA

I want to add formulas and have tried this:

```
For row = ActiveSheets.Range("A" & rows.count).End(xlUp).row To 2 Step -1
    ActiveSheets.Range("BB" & row).Formula = "=SUM(R[0]C[-12]:R[0]C[-1])"
Next row
```

the formula for column BB looks like this:
`=SUM(AP3:BA3)`

Comment: What is the Question/Problem?

Comment: @Jim -  Please define "Crashes VBA".

Comment: the problem is that it crashes.  By crash I mean it "ceases to function". I have to terminate the excel instance and start over

Comment: What is `ActiveSheets`? Why the `s` at the end? (`ActiveSheet` would work -- though it is seldom good VBA to use it). You really should be using `Option Explicit` and you *shouldn't* be using `On Error Resume Next` (not that the code fragment above uses this, but I suspect that you might be using it given this code).

Comment: How do you terminate Excel?    "crash" and "cease to function" are very general terms.

Comment: How many rows of data, could it be that it is just taking a long time.  Maybe you have events firing or formulas that are calculating and it is bogging down excel.

Comment: You also do not need a loop to add a formula, you can add it to the whole range at once.

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
with activesheet
    with .range(.cells(2, "A"), .cells(.rows.count, "A").end(xlup))
        .offset(0, 53).formula = "=sum(ap2:ba2)"
    end with
end with
```